# How do you say "Trust your struggle." in French?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, prépositions

How do you say "Trust your struggle." in French? I've seen it as *confiance à votre lutte*. But the meaning "in" could also be *en* or *dans*.

Comment: This "in" would be translated "en". I would say that often, though not always, "dans" will be more for physical interiority and "en" for the abstract relationship. (One exception is time, where different uses can be "dans" or "en".) Note that your English sentence is a verb, a command, but your French is a noun phrase. To make the French a command you could say "Ayez confiance en votre lutte !" There is also a phrasal verb "Faire confiance **à**" but this is more like finding a person trustworthy. However, see jlliagre's answer concerning idiomaticity.

Comment: Voir peut-être [_Urban Dictionary_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trust%20your%20struggle) : « Accepting when things are tough, it's for your benefit in the end; a life lesson that needs to be learned. ».

Answer (score 5):

*Confiance **à** votre lutte* is incorrect, *(faire) confiance à* can only be used with people.

*Ayez confiance en votre lutte* / *Aie confiance en ta lutte* would then be the literal translation but [is not idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=confiance+en+votre+lutte&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) (zero occurrences in written material, almost zero in the whole web outside this very page and a couple of bogus word by word translations elsewhere).

The same can be said for *confiance en votre combat* suggested in another reply which is unheard and meaningless.

***Ayez confiance en votre étoile*** or ***ayez confiance en votre capacité à lutter*** are examples of what would be idiomatic.

You might say, keeping the same kind of impact the English sentence has:

> ***Faut y croire !***
>
> ***Accroche-toi !***
>
> ***Ne baisse pas les bras !***

Answer (score 1):

Une façon assez littéraire de traduire cette phrase, mais qui peut s'employer dans la langue parlée

- Ayez foi en/dans votre combat/lutte.

Autre possibilité équivalente à la précédente (registre courant)

- Ayez confiance en votre combat/lutte. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ayez+confiance+en+vous&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAyez%20confiance%20en%20vous%3B%2Cc0))

Dans un registre courant  (traduction équivalente aux précédentes)

- Croyez en votre combat/lutte.

On trouve la possibilité suivante (DeepL) ;

- Faites confiance à votre lutte.

C'est une forme que le TLFi déconseille, mais elle est courante ;

> L'expr. « faire confiance à » est née du jargon parlementaire. Dans le bon style, évitez-la. Employez se fier, avoir confiance, s'en remettre, s'en rapporter à... que le tour nouveau a quasi évincés``

Comment: Toutes ces traductions sont littérales, alors que 'Trust your struggle' est idiomatique.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Il me semble que ce ne serait pas le cas ; en se rapportant à la définition du dictionnaire d'Oxford (transitif, To Believe that something is true or correct, **that you can rely on it**) on peut dire, toujours selon ce dictionnaire des choses comme « He trusted her judgement. », « Don't trust what the newspapers say. » ; the verb is synonymous of « to trust in » in this context, as I see it : « Trust in your struggle. » (Ayez foi en vos efforts.). How can the idiomatism be decoded when there is no difference from the standard form ?

Answer (score 0):

La plupart des traductions ici proposées me semblent a bit high class for something like trust your struggle which seems to be more from tattoo parlour and tumblr post than literature.

Je propose : "C'est le métier qui rentre" : expression usuelle quand les gens se font mal ou ont du mal à faire quelque chose. Un commis de cuisine qui se coupe, un enfant qui tombe de vélo, mais aussi une intégration difficile dans une nouvelle entreprise.

Ce n'est pas adapté à des problèmes sentimentaux ou une lutte des classes mais c'est ok pour une nouvelle maman débordée.

Comment: Sauf que (i) 'trust' est positif et (ii) 'c'est le métier qui rentre' a trait à un événement (négatif) spécifique (le c apostrophe a un antécédent).

Comment: (I) Mais struggle est négatif. J'ai pensé à "c'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron". Aucune proposition actuelle me convainc.

Comment: 'Struggle' a trait au présent et 'trust' prédit un avenir radieux. 'C'est le métier qui rentre' n'a pas (explicitement) ce côté positif. Et 'c'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron' n'a pas d'aspect négatif (affaire de patience plus que de _struggle_).

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord. Je pense que l'avenir radieux est une projection. Embrasse tes difficultés. Ce sera peut être juste d'en sortir grandi ou endurci mais réussir n'est pas garanti ni promis par cette expression.

Answer (score 0):

'Tomber sept fois, se relever huit' a une forme de proverbe, est général et allie difficultés actuelles et confiance dans l'avenir. Le principal défaut est que ça n'est pas du français mais du japonais (七転び八起き).